# How much impact does sending unnecessary objects have?

Tags: java, performance

I often find myself in a situation where I need to have a lot of objects as parameters for a method, but all or almost all of those objects can be referenced from another object. In my case, I've got loads of objects such as particle managers and projectile managers which are all attributes of a screen object. Sometimes I just give the entire screen object as the parameter to save time, getting whatever objects I need.

Is this good practice or not? On the one hand, it saves me time, but I don't know the impact of the extra (unnecessary) information also within the screen object when I send it as an argument. Is this inefficient?

Comment: It's no inefficient, because no copy is made. It's just a reference. However, such large objects are called "[god objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)" and thus that's a code smell.

Comment: Shotgun programming is never a good idea, but passing arguments (per se) isn't inefficient.

Comment: You're only sending references to that data, so the overhead is negligible. What I'd be more worried about is that you haven't thought out the right abstractions, and therefore have code where everything needs access to everything, which can make your code hard to test and maintain.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. You don't "send objects". You pass **references** to objects. I.e. passing 3 references instead of 1 means that the JVM has to copy 8 more bytes (or 16 if 64-bit references are used). It's peanuts.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. However, I don't understand how I can make it so that things don't need access to each other. The particle system needs to know what the projectiles are doing, and the projectiles need to know about the creatures they hit, etc.

Comment: There's a different kind of impact besides performance to talk about.  Providing a single object as a param that allows access to all of the things the method needs can future-proof your interface thus allowing you to add new "params" by simply adding to the object and avoid having to change your method signature.

Comment: @BlueCP Yes, those things you mentioned should know each other, but it seems like you make everything know about `Screen`, which makes little sense.

Comment: Screen in my game framework is more akin to a game state. The object I'm talking about is called PlayScreen (which is active when the player is actually playing the game), so it made sense at the time to include stuff relevant to the game state in PlayScreen. I'm pretty sure it's meant to do more than manage UI. It also does stuff like manage ticks in game logic.

Comment: The key thing is clarity, and performance is usually a secondary consideration if that at all.  What is the clearest, and if you have performance concern use a profiler instead of guessing and if that shows a problem, and you might have one.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `Screen` object that has lots of useful fields that your other methods need, and you are too lazy to pass those fields to those methods, so you made the methods all accept a single `Screen` object, then you can just pass your `Screen`.

Hopefully I have understood your situation correctly.

This doesn't actually mean that you are moving unnecessary data around in memory. Objects themselves aren't copied when they are passed as parameters. Only their addresses are copied, which would be the same size of data as if you pass the individual fields. Addresses are all of the same size. Therefore, this probably won't cause a performance problem.

However, this might be bad design. By passing `Screen` to your methods, you are making your methods dependent on `Screen`. If your methods has nothing to do with the UI, they should not depend on `Screen`, right? They should work without a `Screen` as well.

Also, your `Screen` might be a god class and break the Single Responsibility Principle. You might want to refactor that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say in general. Adding an extra parameter means an extra push on the stack, which is generally compiled down to... an extra push on the stack. So regardless of whether it's running in interpreted mode or in compiled mode, you will have one more push per call. But that's fairly cheap. By comparison, getting that same object by making another method call or just dereferencing a variable, could be fast or it could be a little slower - it depends on what happens to be in the L1 and L2 caches at the time, which could vary from call to call. But either way, the object is never copied (unlike in C++). So in summary... it depends, and you probably shouldn't worry about it too much in general. First profile your code if it's slow, and focus only on the parts of the system that are much slower than they could be.

Comment: Saying things like "fairly cheap" and "it depends" is hedging more than you need to. It'll be slower in an only-technically-true way; the impact would probably be sub-nanosecond. It's fair to say there won't be any measurable impact.

Comment: On one call, yes. But on billions or trillions or quadrillions of calls?

Comment: Let's say it's a whole nanosecond (and like I said, it's likely less). In a billion of calls, you've added one whole second. Unless your calls are something as trivial as `++i`, that section of code is going to take long enough that one second is (a) insignificant, and (b) lost in the noise of other activity, like GC, so it'll be hard to even measure. If you really do need to account for and optimize every second from a billion calls, Java is probably not the language for you anyway. All of this to say that I still stand by my assertion that you're hedging more than needed.

Answer (score 0):

*To me*, passing a single `context` - this is how I call that "transfer" object, is appropriate. As said, if you want to support future additions or removals of some parts of that object - this is easy to do.

But there are cases when I am only pro-passing separate individual pieces. This is the case when you want to test a method and if some more objects are needed for a method - I want tests to fail.

```
 // context contains first and second
 public void testMe(Context context) {

 }
```

vs

```
 public void testMe(String first, String second){

 }
```

Adding one more parameter to the `context`, like `String third` - will most probably make your test pass; but adding one more parameter to a method that expect two... It's easy to ignore writing a unit test, it's a lot harder to ignore a compilation error. So sometimes, we have code that takes more arguments for this reason.

As far as performance, I doubt you will ever feel a difference (even if one exists), after all, passing objects is actually passing a reference.